# How can l add a screenshot when l ask a public question on stackoverflow.com?

Tags: support

Like at

[Drop Commit is disabled in WebStorm's Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72437636/drop-commit-is-disabled-in-webstorms-git)

If you look at the history this post you can see that a l couldn't made the screenshot like it now.

Comment: Click the image button in the editor, or if you've copied it, ctrl-v in the editor. You need 10 reputation to embed an image IIRC, which you're solidly above right now. Even if you have <10 rep, you can still upload, just not embed

Answer (score 13):

There are two general guidelines I like to follow when it comes to adding images on Stack Overflow.

1. **Don't do it.**
2. Don't do it *yet*.

Images aren't indexed and aren't searchable, so those who aren't able to see the image (and yes there are a number of folks in this category, and this isn't limited to accessibility) won't be able to offer anything to help you.

In my assessment it's better to describe with words what it is you're running into, and only offer an image as *clarification*.  If your question was *just* the image that's problematic.

Note:  your question looks more oriented around Git rather than the tool itself.  [Dropping a commit](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/undo-changes.html#f69d50ae) as a feature reads a *lot* like [a rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) - but the way IntelliJ describes it is probably version control-agnostic.  You could have asked a question oriented around how to drop a commit in Git or why you couldn't do that in your master branch in Git as opposed to the tool itself.

Once you clear the [new user restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user) you *should* be able to do it...just click the image icon in the question and upload it.  It will auto-generate what it needs to actually display the image in the question for you.

Comment: The image should be use as a resource, to explain "whatever you are trying to explain", since an image is worth a thousand words.  It's certainly not required to explain what you are attempting to do with your MRE, since it's a MRE, it shouldn't be that complicated.

Comment: Images (including drawings) can be particularly useful for UI mockups or to explain what is going wrong in a GUI program.

Comment: I don't understand, why does many users mark minus on my question?

Comment: @maxim.saharov 1) this is already documented around the site, so there should be no need for this to be asked again. 2) images are almost always used poorly by new users, ergo the restriction, so a new user asking why they can't post an image is statistically  going to result in yet another poor question.

Comment: @user4581301 I wrote this text “If you look at the history this post you can see that a l couldn't made the screenshot like it now.” in this post. Is everything OK now? New users who was read this answer all understand?

Comment: @user4581301 "so a new user asking why they can't post an image is statistically going to result in yet another poor question."
- If I have this problem and I have found this post where have understand answer from support, why this question is poor question? 
By the way, marked minus can users who can't  have this problem. And another question - for what does do it?

Comment: @user4581301 It is at least strange, don't write argument and marked simply minus. IMO it is a simple question with example, and simple has understood answer from support.

Comment: @maxim.saharov The question you asked made good use of the image. When you've spent more time on the site you'll see how unusual this is.

Comment: @user4581301 How did l should it ask? If l ask without foto, somebody tell me that it also poor question, isn't it? Could you write me how l should it ask?

Comment: Your question is fine as it is. You used the image exactly the way it should be used. My point is your question is one of the exceedingly rare good questions with an image.

Answer (score -3):

Now l understand why l could not add a screenshot. When I made my fist post I have only 1 rep. You must have >10 rep to add a screenshot.